# Load an HTML file via a button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I am trying to call a HTML file when a button is clicked using jQuery.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Buttons</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="buttonscript.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
<input type ="button" id="myButton" value="Click Here">

<div id="dictionary">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('myButton').click(function(){
        $('dictionary').load('a.html');
        return false;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two wrong things in your script:

1. You are not assigning the selectors with the right syntax;
2. You are using document ready syntax on an external file;

The first point is fixed using `#` before the id name and `.` before the class name (see below the fix).

The document.ready() function should be included into the html itself: it tells jquery to run the script only when the DOM is ready. Including it in an external file will make jQuery check for DOM ready on the external file and not on the one you are including to.
So move your script to the html itself and change it a bit:

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(e){
    // prevent page submit
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // load the page into #dictionary
        $('#dictionary').load('a.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to have my script as a seperate file to my html file, just the way my lecturer requested it to be. used the above script but all it does is displays the name of my html file im calling "a.html" not the actual file

Comment: Sorry! I fixed the error in the script. I used .html but it should be .load

Answer (score 0):

Add `#` to your selectors like, and instead of using `return false`, you could prevent default behavior of the button (if the `type` attribute is set to `submit`).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(event){

        // prevent page submit
        event.preventDefault(); 

        // load the page into #dictionary
        $('#dictionary').load('a.html');

    });
});
```

Comment: Still nothing happening. I added some text into the dictionary div and when i click the button the text disappears, thats the most its doing. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: I highly recommend creating a fiddle for this or at least commit your files to the server, and put the link here in a comment. The path for `a.html` could not be right or, the file doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Additionally, you should check your console log, and report the errors you catch here.

Comment: @AdamAzad why do you think it is necessary to use stopPropagation? it works fine with preventing the default behaviour only. To stop propagation can lead to undesired results if it is not used with the right syntax. (just for my knowledge here)

Comment: Well, I would vouch for your comment, but I use it when binding elements to js actions. In a such case, I would drop `stopPropagation()`. Thanks!

Comment: trust me it is not needed at all. My applications use a lot of buttons designed with only preventDefault and everything is fine and smooth!